# Training a network for machine learning purpose, dividing the dataset in portions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a big dataset that can't be loaded in RAM due to lack of enough memory.
What I am trying to do is train the model in x portions of the dataset to get the final model trained in the whole dataset as following:

```
num_divisione_dataset=4
div_tr = int(int(len(x_tr))/num_divisione_dataset)
div_val = int(2160/num_divisione_dataset)
num_training = int(math.ceil(100/num_divisione_dataset))

for i in range(0,num_divisione_dataset-1):

  model.fit(
  x_tr[div_tr*i:div_tr*(i+1)], y_tr[div_tr*i:div_tr*(i+1)],
  batch_size = 32,
  callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback],
  validation_data = (x_val, y_val),
  epochs = 25 
  )
```

Is it a right way to train a model?

Answer (score 1):

The `batch_size = 32` already is a way to train the model in batches of size 32. It seems you have two levels of batching, one that you built yourself an another that's provided by Tensorflow.

The problem with your batching is `epochs=25`. The Tensorflow batches alternate within an epoch, and the next epoch it loops again over the Tensorflow batches. But you first train 25 epochs with your first batch, then 25 epochs with your second batch, etcetera.

I'm not sure this is best solved in software. It might be easier to just ignore the lack of RAM, and let the OS swap to disk. Buying more RAM could be another viable route. But a possible software route would be an [input pipeline](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data)

Comment: Isn't right that I take 25epochs for the first portion, 25 for the second and so on? I mean that's how training a model works.
Instead of having the whole dataset in 100 epochs, I have 4 steps and 25 epochs each. There are no duplication of training I think...

Comment: No, that's not right. Each epoch, the weights are updated - training works via a gradient-descent of the error. In the last 25 epochs, you only use 25% of your dataset.  This is a problem, because at that moment you should already be near the minimum error, where the gradient is almost zero. You need all the data there to get a good gradient.

Comment: but If I just use 25% and then I re-trained on the other 25% and so on till get the whole dataset, isn't the gradient updated each time? So at the end of the training I should get a good gradient value and a good minimization of the function related to the whole dataset...?

Comment: @Diego: The gradient is the gradient of the error as function of the weights. And the error in turn is the difference between the ground truth (`y`) and the current neural network output. You have 4 different errors (the 4 parts of `y`) with 4 different gradients.

Comment: that's true but everytime that you finish a step, the following one (step) start from the error of the previous error...is not true? So at the end of the computation you have a final error that is update every time and every time should be less because of the logic of the gradient descent.

Comment: You keep getting stuck at **the** error. We define typically "error" as "ground truth minus calculated outcome, squared and summed". You have 4 datasets, with 4 inputs, 4 calculated outputs, 4 ground truths, and therefor 4 different errors. When `i==0`, you optimize the weights for the first error (over 25 epochs). When `i==1`, you take those weights and start optimizing them for the _second_ error, optimizing for another 25 epochs.

Comment: ok, many thanks, I now get it!
So the solution in order to obtain a good dataset is to pass the whole dataset to the model...?
There is no another way to train the model using the whole dataset?

Comment: @DiegoRando: You need to pass the whole dataset, yes, but that doesn't mean you need to pass it entirely in RAM.

Answer (score -1):

Put your data in a CSV file. Then use [make_csv_dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset) to load it in batches and pass it to `model.fit`. Make sure to set `num_epochs=1`, otherwise the data set will loop forever.

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv) you can find an example on how to use it.

A minimal code should be:

```
DATASET_PATH=#path of the csv file
LABEL_COLUMN=#name of the column in csv file representing output
COLUMNS=["a","b","c","d"] #name of the columns in csv file representing input
BATCH_SIZE=int(len(x_tr)/num_divisione_dataset)

def get_dataset(batch_size = 5):
    return tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(DATASET_PATH, batch_size = batch_size, label_name = LABEL_COLUMN, num_epochs = 1)

dataset = get_dataset(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
train_size= #put the train_dataset size here
train_dataset = dataset.take(train_size)
val_dataset = dataset.skip(train_size)

columns=[]
for c in COLUMNS:
    cln = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(c, shape=())
    columns.append(cln)

feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(columns)
model = Sequential()
model.add(feature_layer)
model.add...# add your NN layers
model.compile... #parameters to compile

history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=val_dataset,
    callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback],
    epochs=25,
)
```

Comment: How would I train the model on the dataset with just 1 epoch?
Loading the dataset and train the model on the it should be different steps...

Comment: Maybe I was too much hermetic: I'm modifying the code adding some more info. The `num_epochs` in `make_csv_dataset` is not the number of epochs of training (thet is  `epochs`  in  `model.fit`) It is the number of times the file mus be read to provide data to the dataset.

Comment: i am trying to convert the list (x_Tr and all the others) in csv files, but the csv is way too big

Comment: There is also tf.data.TFRecordDataset to read and create a dataset from a file, previously created using tf.io.TFRecordWriter, and it can be also a zipped file, but never used it. The documentation provides some examples.